# How to save foreign keys (SQL)

Tags: php, sql

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO deelnemer (Account_ID, BehaaldePunten, School_ID, Icon_ID) VALUES
          ('Account_ID', (SELECT ID FROM account WHERE Gebruikersnaam = '$name'),
          0,
          ('School_ID', (SELECT ID FROM school WHERE Naam = '$school'),
          ('Icon_ID', (SELECT ID FROM icon WHERE ID = 1))
          INNER JOIN account ON deelnemer.Account_ID = account.ID,
          INNER JOIN school ON deelnemer.School_ID = school.ID";
          $result = $connection->prepare($sql);
          $result->execute();
```

Hey guys, I'm pretty new to SQL. I need to save a row which contains some foreign keys and I tried some stuff already but nothing seems to work. I hope you can help me xX

This is the error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN
>   account ON deelnemer.Account_ID = account.ID, INNER JO' at line 6' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GameBattle\test\Register_Modal.php:36 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GameBattle\test\Register_Modal.php(36):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GameBattle\test\login.php(84):
>   require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GameBattle\test\Register_Modal.php on line 36

Comment: What problem you are facing? Any errors?

Comment: The foreign key as the name suggests must already exist in its original table. If the error doesn't come from there it would be wise to add the error message as @HimanshuUpadhyay says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replacing  :

```
('Account_ID', (SELECT ID FROM account WHERE Gebruikersnaam = '$name')
          0,
          ('School_ID', (SELECT ID FROM school WHERE Naam = '$school'),
```

with just :

```
(SELECT ID FROM account WHERE Gebruikersnaam = '$name',
          0,
 SELECT ID FROM school WHERE Naam = '$school'
etc... )
```

Comment: Thanks @Laura . Please mark the question as answered. :-)